# No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - site/tmp/pids/puma.pid (Errno::ENOENT)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, puma

I have deployed a Rails app manually to virtual private server (VPS) and trying to get it to run. The VPS has Ubuntu 18.04, Apache2, Ruby 2.5.1, & Rails 5.2.1. Puma 3.12.0 is the web server. Everything ran well in development. In production, when I run puma, I get the following:

```
[28751] Puma starting in cluster mode...
[28751] * Version 3.12.0 (ruby 2.5.1-p57), codename: Llamas in Pajamas
[28751] * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
[28751] * Environment: production
[28751] * Process workers: 2
[28751] * Preloading application
[28751] * Listening on unix:///home/kenneth/site/tmp/sockets/puma.sock
[28751] * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000
[28751] ! WARNING: Detected 1 Thread(s) started in app boot:
[28751] ! #<Thread:0x00005643a2eda878@/home/kenneth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:297 sleep> - /home/kenneth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:299:in `sleep'
[28751] Use Ctrl-C to stop
Traceback (most recent call last):
    11: from /home/kenneth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'
    10: from /home/kenneth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
     9: from /home/kenneth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/bin/puma:23:in `<main>'
     8: from /home/kenneth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/bin/puma:23:in `load'
     7: from /home/kenneth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/puma-3.12.0/bin/puma:10:in `<top (required)>'
     6: from /home/kenneth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/cli.rb:78:in `run'
     5: from /home/kenneth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/launcher.rb:184:in `run'
     4: from /home/kenneth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/cluster.rb:458:in `run'
     3: from /home/kenneth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/launcher.rb:104:in `write_state'
     2: from /home/kenneth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/launcher.rb:131:in `write_pid'
     1: from /home/kenneth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/launcher.rb:131:in `open' /home/kenneth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/launcher.rb:131:in `initialize': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - site/tmp/pids/puma.pid (Errno::ENOENT)
```

I searched the knowledge base here. One similar inquiry concerning a puma.pid was found but the solution was to create the tmp/pids directories. In my case,  those directories & the puma.pid exist. The output appears to indicate that the initialization of the Puma::Launcher instance failed and refers to the write_pid method circa line 131 in launcher.rb. I have included the code from the launcher.rb and puma.rb and  files. Please help me to understand what the problem is and how it can be resolved.

launch.rb

```
require 'puma/events'
require 'puma/detect'

require 'puma/cluster'
require 'puma/single'

require 'puma/const'

require 'puma/binder'

module Puma
  # Puma::Launcher is the single entry point for starting a Puma server based on user
  # configuration. It is responsible for taking user supplied arguments and resolving them
  # with configuration in `config/puma.rb` or `config/puma/<env>.rb`.
  #
  # It is responsible for either launching a cluster of Puma workers or a single
  # puma server.
  class Launcher
    KEYS_NOT_TO_PERSIST_IN_STATE = [
       :logger, :lowlevel_error_handler,
       :before_worker_shutdown, :before_worker_boot, :before_worker_fork,
       :after_worker_boot, :before_fork, :on_restart
     ]
    # Returns an instance of Launcher
    #
    # +conf+ A Puma::Configuration object indicating how to run the server.
    #
    # +launcher_args+ A Hash that currently has one required key `:events`,
    # this is expected to hold an object similar to an `Puma::Events.stdio`,
    # this object will be responsible for broadcasting Puma's internal state
    # to a logging destination. An optional key `:argv` can be supplied,
    # this should be an array of strings, these arguments are re-used when
    # restarting the puma server.
    #
    # Examples:
    #
    #   conf = Puma::Configuration.new do |user_config|
    #     user_config.threads 1, 10
    #     user_config.app do |env|
    #       [200, {}, ["hello world"]]
    #     end
    #   end
    #   Puma::Launcher.new(conf, events: Puma::Events.stdio).run
    def initialize(conf, launcher_args={})
      @runner        = nil
      @events        = launcher_args[:events] || Events::DEFAULT
      @argv          = launcher_args[:argv] || []
      @original_argv = @argv.dup
      @config        = conf

      @binder        = Binder.new(@events)
      @binder.import_from_env

      @environment = conf.environment

      # Advertise the Configuration
      Puma.cli_config = @config if defined?(Puma.cli_config)

      @config.load

      @options = @config.options
      @config.clamp

      generate_restart_data

      if clustered? && (Puma.jruby? || Puma.windows?)
        unsupported 'worker mode not supported on JRuby or Windows'
      end

      if @options[:daemon] && Puma.windows?
        unsupported 'daemon mode not supported on Windows'
      end

      Dir.chdir(@restart_dir)

      prune_bundler if prune_bundler?

      @environment = @options[:environment] if @options[:environment]
      set_rack_environment

      if clustered?
        @events.formatter = Events::PidFormatter.new
        @options[:logger] = @events

        @runner = Cluster.new(self, @events)
      else
        @runner = Single.new(self, @events)
      end
      Puma.stats_object = @runner

      @status = :run
    end

    attr_reader :binder, :events, :config, :options, :restart_dir

    # Return stats about the server
    def stats
      @runner.stats
    end

    # Write a state file that can be used by pumactl to control
    # the server
    def write_state
      write_pid

      path = @options[:state]
      return unless path

      require 'puma/state_file'

      sf = StateFile.new
      sf.pid = Process.pid
      sf.control_url = @options[:control_url]
      sf.control_auth_token = @options[:control_auth_token]

      sf.save path
    end

    # Delete the configured pidfile
    def delete_pidfile
      path = @options[:pidfile]
      File.unlink(path) if path && File.exist?(path)
    end
# The problem appears to pertain to this method
#
    # If configured, write the pid of the current process out
    # to a file.
    def write_pid
      path = @options[:pidfile]
      return unless path
# The error output indicated the following line (131) to be the culprit
      File.open(path, 'w') { |f| f.puts Process.pid }
      cur = Process.pid
      at_exit do
        delete_pidfile if cur == Process.pid
      end
    end

    # Begin async shutdown of the server
    def halt
      @status = :halt
      @runner.halt
    end

    # Begin async shutdown of the server gracefully
    def stop
      @status = :stop
      @runner.stop
    end

    # Begin async restart of the server
    def restart
      @status = :restart
      @runner.restart
    end

    # Begin a phased restart if supported
    def phased_restart
      unless @runner.respond_to?(:phased_restart) and @runner.phased_restart
        log "* phased-restart called but not available, restarting normally."
        return restart
      end
      true
    end

    # Run the server. This blocks until the server is stopped
    def run
      previous_env =
        if defined?(Bundler)
          env = Bundler::ORIGINAL_ENV.dup
          # add -rbundler/setup so we load from Gemfile when restarting
          bundle = "-rbundler/setup"
          env["RUBYOPT"] = [env["RUBYOPT"], bundle].join(" ").lstrip unless env["RUBYOPT"].to_s.include?(bundle)
          env
        else
          ENV.to_h
        end

      @config.clamp

      @config.plugins.fire_starts self

      setup_signals
      set_process_title
      @runner.run

      case @status
      when :halt
        log "* Stopping immediately!"
      when :run, :stop
        graceful_stop
      when :restart
        log "* Restarting..."
        ENV.replace(previous_env)
        @runner.before_restart
        restart!
      when :exit
        # nothing
      end
    end

    # Return which tcp port the launcher is using, if it's using TCP
    def connected_port
      @binder.connected_port
    end

    def restart_args
      cmd = @options[:restart_cmd]
      if cmd
        cmd.split(' ') + @original_argv
      else
        @restart_argv
      end
    end

    private

    def reload_worker_directory
      @runner.reload_worker_directory if @runner.respond_to?(:reload_worker_directory)
    end

    def restart!
      @config.run_hooks :on_restart, self

      if Puma.jruby?
        close_binder_listeners

        require 'puma/jruby_restart'
        JRubyRestart.chdir_exec(@restart_dir, restart_args)
      elsif Puma.windows?
        close_binder_listeners

        argv = restart_args
        Dir.chdir(@restart_dir)
        Kernel.exec(*argv)
      else
        redirects = {:close_others => true}
        @binder.listeners.each_with_index do |(l, io), i|
          ENV["PUMA_INHERIT_#{i}"] = "#{io.to_i}:#{l}"
          redirects[io.to_i] = io.to_i
        end

        argv = restart_args
        Dir.chdir(@restart_dir)
        argv += [redirects] if RUBY_VERSION >= '1.9'
        Kernel.exec(*argv)
      end
    end

    def prune_bundler
      return unless defined?(Bundler)
      puma = Bundler.rubygems.loaded_specs("puma")
      dirs = puma.require_paths.map { |x| File.join(puma.full_gem_path, x) }
      puma_lib_dir = dirs.detect { |x| File.exist? File.join(x, '../bin/puma-wild') }

      unless puma_lib_dir
        log "! Unable to prune Bundler environment, continuing"
        return
      end

      deps = puma.runtime_dependencies.map do |d|
        spec = Bundler.rubygems.loaded_specs(d.name)
        "#{d.name}:#{spec.version.to_s}"
      end

      log '* Pruning Bundler environment'
      home = ENV['GEM_HOME']
      Bundler.with_clean_env do
        ENV['GEM_HOME'] = home
        ENV['PUMA_BUNDLER_PRUNED'] = '1'
        wild = File.expand_path(File.join(puma_lib_dir, "../bin/puma-wild"))
        args = [Gem.ruby, wild, '-I', dirs.join(':'), deps.join(',')] + @original_argv
        # Ruby 2.0+ defaults to true which breaks socket activation
        args += [{:close_others => false}] if RUBY_VERSION >= '2.0'
        Kernel.exec(*args)
      end
    end

    def log(str)
      @events.log str
    end

    def clustered?
      (@options[:workers] || 0) > 0
    end

    def unsupported(str)
      @events.error(str)
      raise UnsupportedOption
    end

    def graceful_stop
      @runner.stop_blocked
      log "=== puma shutdown: #{Time.now} ==="
      log "- Goodbye!"
    end

    def set_process_title
      Process.respond_to?(:setproctitle) ? Process.setproctitle(title) : $0 = title
    end

    def title
      buffer  = "puma #{Puma::Const::VERSION} (#{@options[:binds].join(',')})"
      buffer += " [#{@options[:tag]}]" if @options[:tag] && !@options[:tag].empty?
      buffer
    end

    def set_rack_environment
      @options[:environment] = environment
      ENV['RACK_ENV'] = environment
    end

    def environment
      @environment
    end

    def prune_bundler?
      @options[:prune_bundler] && clustered? && !@options[:preload_app]
    end

    def close_binder_listeners
      @binder.listeners.each do |l, io|
        io.close
        uri = URI.parse(l)
        next unless uri.scheme == 'unix'
        File.unlink("#{uri.host}#{uri.path}")
      end
    end


    def generate_restart_data
      if dir = @options[:directory]
        @restart_dir = dir

      elsif Puma.windows?
        # I guess the value of PWD is garbage on windows so don't bother
        # using it.
        @restart_dir = Dir.pwd

        # Use the same trick as unicorn, namely favor PWD because
        # it will contain an unresolved symlink, useful for when
        # the pwd is /data/releases/current.
      elsif dir = ENV['PWD']
        s_env = File.stat(dir)
        s_pwd = File.stat(Dir.pwd)

        if s_env.ino == s_pwd.ino and (Puma.jruby? or s_env.dev == s_pwd.dev)
          @restart_dir = dir
        end
      end

      @restart_dir ||= Dir.pwd

      # if $0 is a file in the current directory, then restart
      # it the same, otherwise add -S on there because it was
      # picked up in PATH.
      #
      if File.exist?($0)
        arg0 = [Gem.ruby, $0]
      else
        arg0 = [Gem.ruby, "-S", $0]
      end

      # Detect and reinject -Ilib from the command line, used for testing without bundler
      # cruby has an expanded path, jruby has just "lib"
      lib = File.expand_path "lib"
      arg0[1,0] = ["-I", lib] if [lib, "lib"].include?($LOAD_PATH[0])

      if defined? Puma::WILD_ARGS
        @restart_argv = arg0 + Puma::WILD_ARGS + @original_argv
      else
        @restart_argv = arg0 + @original_argv
      end
    end

    def setup_signals
      begin
        Signal.trap "SIGUSR2" do
          restart
        end
      rescue Exception
        log "*** SIGUSR2 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable!"
      end

      unless Puma.jruby?
        begin
          Signal.trap "SIGUSR1" do
            phased_restart
          end
        rescue Exception
          log "*** SIGUSR1 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable!"
        end
      end

      begin
        Signal.trap "SIGTERM" do
          graceful_stop

          raise SignalException, "SIGTERM"
        end
      rescue Exception
        log "*** SIGTERM not implemented, signal based gracefully stopping unavailable!"
      end

      begin
        Signal.trap "SIGINT" do
          if Puma.jruby?
            @status = :exit
            graceful_stop
            exit
          end

          stop
        end
      rescue Exception
        log "*** SIGINT not implemented, signal based gracefully stopping unavailable!"
      end

      begin
        Signal.trap "SIGHUP" do
          if @runner.redirected_io?
            @runner.redirect_io
          else
            stop
          end
        end
      rescue Exception
        log "*** SIGHUP not implemented, signal based logs reopening unavailable!"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

puma.rb

```
# Puma can serve each request in a thread from an internal thread pool.
# The `threads` method setting takes two numbers: a minimum and maximum.
# Any libraries that use thread pools should be configured to match
# the maximum value specified for Puma. Default is set to 5 threads for minimum
# and maximum; this matches the default thread size of Active Record.
#

app_dir = "site"      # File.expand_path("../..", __FILE__)
shared_dir = "    #{app_dir}/tmp"
    # Set up socket location
bind 'unix:///home/kenneth/site/tmp/sockets/puma.sock' #"unix://#{shared_dir}/sockets/puma.sock"

threads_count = Integer(ENV['RAILS_MAX_THREADS'] || 5)
threads threads_count, threads_count

rackup      DefaultRackup

    # Specifies the `port` that Puma will listen on to receive requests; default is 3000.
    #
port        ENV['PORT'] || 3000

    # Specifies the `environment` that Puma will run in.
    # environment ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || 'development'
    #
rails_env = ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || 'production'
environment rails_env

# Logging
# stdout_redirect "    #{shared_dir}/log/puma.stdout.log", "  #{shared_dir}/log/puma.stderr.log", true


# config.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
# config.logger = Logger.new(STDERR)

# Set master PID and state locations
pidfile "    #{shared_dir}/pids/puma.pid"
state_path "    #{shared_dir}/pids/puma.state"
activate_control_app

# Specifies the number of `workers` to boot in clustered mode.
# Workers are forked webserver processes. If using threads and workers together
# the concurrency of the application would be max `threads` * `workers`.
# Workers do not work on JRuby or Windows (both of which do not support
# processes).
#
workers Integer(ENV['WEB_CONCURRENCY'] || 2)

# Use the `preload_app!` method when specifying a `workers` number.
# This directive tells Puma to first boot the application and load code
# before forking the application. This takes advantage of Copy On Write
# process behavior so workers use less memory.
#
preload_app!

on_worker_boot do
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection # if defined?(ActiveRecord)
                 ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(YAML.load_file("#{app_dir}/config/database.yml")[rails_env])
end

# Allow puma to be restarted by `rails restart` command.
plugin :tmp_restart
```

Comment: Check the permissions on the directory `site/tmp/pids` and if `puma.pid` already exists there (and Puma is not running) then delete that file. (or verify its permissions as well). Also try a full path in `app_dir`, not a relative path. Next, read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with emphasis on **minimal**.

Comment: Thanks anothermh. That worked.